# How to call a customhelper in CodeCeptjs?

Tags: protractor, codeceptjs

How to call a method defined in customhelper?

**MycustomHelper**

```
const { Helper } = codeceptjs;
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const expect = chai.expect;

class MyHelper extends Helper {

  async JavaScriptclick(LocatorVale)  {
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);       
    browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.xpath(LocatorVale))); 

  }

}

module.exports = MyHelper;
```

Code.js

```
helpers: {
    MyHelper: {
      require: './myhelper_helper.js',
    },
```

Stepfile.js

```
Scenario('Add a new user group', (I, MyHelper) => {  
   MyHelper.JavaScriptclick(‘.badged-button.mat-raised-button.mat-primar')
});
```

If I execute the above code, I get the below error

```
   Add a new user group:
     Object of type MyHelper is not defined in container
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. I need to click on a button, but I.click is not able to locate the button. So I had to use javascriptclick in this case. However I.executescript is also not working. Hence I need to use native protractor commands as it works only this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no need to call helper by it's name.
All methods are added in actor (`I`) object

As said in documentation:

> Methods of Helper class will be available in tests in `I` object. This abstracts test scenarios from the implementation and allows easily switching between backends.

https://codecept.io/helpers/#extending-codeceptjs-with-custom-helopers

So, in test:

```
Scenario('Add a new user group', (I) => {  
   I.JavaScriptclick(‘.badged-button.mat-raised-button.mat-primar')
});
```